# Python How To Search List For Keyword And Output Column Number of Match

Tags: python

Hey I'm looking to search a keyword against a list and output the column number of match.

Example input list:

```
['dom perignon', 'aircheck', 'linkrunner']
```

Say For Example, I want to search

```
aircheck
```

I'd like to recieve the desired output

```
2
```

because it is the second column in the list.

Comment: If it's as simple as it looks, use `.index()`

Answer (score -1):

```
list_=['dom perignon', 'aircheck', 'linkrunner']
word='aircheck'
counter=1
for item in list_:
    if word in item:
        print(counter)
        break
    counter+=1
else:
    print(-1)
```

the counter keeps track of what column the for loop is checking. If the word is in item, it prints the column and breaks from the for loop. If the word is not found, it prints -1.